# Combined complexity of phases of external sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

External sort complexity has been well described [here](http://www.tcs.fudan.edu.cn/rudolf/Courses/Algorithms/Alg_cs_06w/Resources/cache_sort.pdf). On page 2 and 3, it well describes the `phase1` and `phase2`.  I understand complexities described in each step. My question is on the line `Summing up the costs of phase 1 and phase 2 we get the total running time of
Θ(n log2
(n/m))` mentioned on page 4. After pseudo code.

From my understanding - complexity of phase 1 is:
O(MlogM) to sort all records in the main memory buffer.
We fill the buffers N/M times thus effectively O(N/M * M log M) which is O(NlogM).

How does :

Phase 1:  O(NlogM).

and

Phase 2: Θ(n log m/n)

combined result in Θ(n log2
(n/m)) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assessing the performance of external algorithms, we typically only count the number of disk operations needed to execute an algorithm. The paper defines `n = N/B` and `m = M/B`.

Phase 1 actually only needs `Θ(n)` disk operations, since we only read and write each block once. It is now obvious that `Θ(n) + Θ(n log n/m) = Θ(n log n/m)`

Comment: Oh I get it, just curious `we typically only count the number of disk operations` - why ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: Because disk operations are really really really slow compared to anything else involved in a sort.  Reading a single byte from the harddrive takes roughly the same amount of time as 52,000,000 CPU cycles.  Even reading from RAM takes ~20,000-332,000 CPU cycles.  Cache is king.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: The external memory model lets you analyze algorithms with regard to their memory locality. It's useful because the memory hierarchy has the important property that the smaller caches (`L1`, `L2`) are much faster than the larger caches, RAM or even disk. So often in practice we get much faster algorithms if we minimize cache misses/loads+stores from a medium higher in the memory hierarchy, because these *tend* to dominate the overall runtime

Comment: Obviously this doesn't mean that you can always conclude that if you minimize I/O, you get a fast algorithm. For example, if you use Bogo sort instead of Merge sort in phase 1 of the external mergesort algorithm you cited, you get the same run time in terms of I/O accesses, but your program might never finish (and if it does, it will be really really slow)